# Multi Calculo entre Campos dentro de um While

Tags: javascript

Não sei como proceder nesse. No código a baixo
tenho um loop que me retorna  quantidade e valor por linha 
como fazer esse calculo dinamicamente por linha
       `loop{ 
linha 1 <input type="text" name="qtd" > x <input type="text" name="valor" > = result 
linha 2 <input type="text" name="qtd" > x <input type="text" name="valor" > = result
linha 3 <input type="text" name="qtd" > x <input type="text" name="valor" > = result 
}`....

Comment: Não consegui entender nem a pergunta, nem o código. Poderia detalhar melhor, por favor?

Comment: imagina uma tabela com 5 ou mais linhas.... cada linha tem 2 campos unidade  e valor   eu queria fazer esse calculo dinamicamente por linha então linha '1'   eu colocaria a quantidade no campo e iria multiplicar pelo valor contido no campo 2

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que entendi, você quer uma calculadora?

```js
var content = document.querySelector("#content");
for(var i=0;i<10;i++){
  (function(){
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    var input1 = document.createElement("input");
    var input2 = document.createElement("input");
    var result = document.createElement("span");
    input1.oninput=input2.oninput=function(e){
      result.innerHTML = Number(input1.value)*Number(input2.value);
    }
    div.appendChild(input1);
    div.appendChild(document.createTextNode(" x "));
    div.appendChild(input2);
    div.appendChild(document.createTextNode(" = "));
    div.appendChild(result);
    content.appendChild(div);
  })();
}
```

```html
<span id="content"></span>
```

Comment: Correto.... isso mesmo  mais seria em varias linhas

Comment: Quantos ao certo?

Comment: cada linha com um ma calculadora dessa

Comment: Quantas linhas? definida pelo usuario?

Comment: não tem como estimar numeros de linha pois essas linhas estariam dentro de um loop vindo de uma consulta no mysql

Comment: bom, dai quando retornar a consulta no mysql é só colocar ali no for....

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24240/discussion-between-matheus-cristian-and-fabio-henrique).

Comment: Ok isso mesmo... só não sei como passar uma variavel para o campo 2